# How to POST url and parameters using Linking.openURL() from React native application

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to redirect url which is open in default browser in React-Native.

I am using Linking.openURL() its redirecting properly but I also want to POST data/parameters with it.

There is a only way which I find is GET method and send data with url like this: Linking.openURL('https://yoururl.com/?cart_token=[token]'); but I don't want to send parameters with url.

How to use POST method with Linking.openURL()?

Comment: POST is not supported.

Comment: Thanks @SaachiTech is there any other way to redirect and POST parameters also